# how to plot coordinate points to an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have retrieved coordinate points of an image from this code to an array.how can I plot this coordinate points in to an image.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
edge = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)

ans = []
for y in range(0, edge.shape[0]):
    for x in range(0, edge.shape[1]):
        if edge[y, x] != 0:
            ans = ans + [[x, y]]
ans = np.array(ans)

print(ans.shape)
print(ans[0:10, :])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
edge = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)

plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edge,cmap = 'gray')
plt.show()
```